# Can I use a buffer on my bias voltage net?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, biasing, guitar-pedal

I'm a french stompbox / bass guitar pedal hobbyist, probably very bad at designing them.
I've been thinking about bias voltage nets for some time, and how inefficient they sometimes are.
I've studied multiple "classic" distortion and boost pedals, and bias voltage seems to be a tricky thing, some designs just put voltage dividers before every FETs or OPamp channels, increasing passive power consumption, and making the math for voltage drops across the whole circuit very confusing. Sometimes it's just one voltage divider located at the power supply that provides the whole thing with an (ideally) +4.5V bias.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCWw4j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was wondering if it's possible to make a sort of "virtual ground" using a power-supply-specialized OPamp, by buffering the bias voltage and using it as the 0V reference between a +4.5V and -4.5V supply inside the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTcgPz.png)</sup>

Comment: Yes that’s pretty routine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact I have seen petal circuits using this technique... But typically for low power audio amplifiers etc, the capacitor bridge with resistors is good enough...

One argument could be this is more power friendly, as you can use very large resistors and do not waste quiescent current on the bridge, assuming a low power op-amp.